# How to convert RTSP stream into flv/swf Stream (w. ffmpeg)?

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam, rtsp, streaming-flv-video

I want embed a webcam stream (From geovision video server) into a website. Unfortunately only the rtsp stream gives direct access to the video data.

I tried a bunch of different variants. With this version I got no errors:

```
openRTSP -b 50000 -w 352 -h 288 -f 5 -v -c -u admin password rtsp://xxxxxx.dyndns.org:8554/CH001.sdp | \
ffmpeg -r 5 -b 256000 -f mp4 -i - http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm
```

Unfortunately I get no video. Sometimes I see a single frame of the webcam, but no livestream.

This is my ffserver.conf

```
Port 8090
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxClients 200
MaxBandwidth 20000
CustomLog /var/log/flvserver/access.log

NoDaemon

# Server Status
<Stream stat.html>
Format status
</Stream>

<Feed feed1.ffm>
File /tmp/feed1.ffm
FileMaxSize 200K
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed>

# SWF output - great for testing
<Stream test.swf>
 # the source feed
 Feed feed1.ffm
 # the output stream format - SWF = flash
 Format swf
 #VideoCodec flv
 # this must match the ffmpeg -r argument
 VideoFrameRate 5
 # another quality tweak
 VideoBitRate 256K
 # quality ranges - 1-31 (1 = best, 31 = worst)
 VideoQMin 1
 VideoQMax 3
 VideoSize 352x288
 # wecams don't have audio
 NoAudio
</Stream>
```

What am I doing wrong? THe test.swf seems to load forever...

Answer (score 2):

Tried something like this with `vlc` and it worked for me...

```
vlc.exe -I http -vv camURL :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=0,scale=0,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=addr:availablePort}
```

**camurl** is the url of the camera....

**addr** is the address where you want the `httpstream` to be sent to...

**availablePort** is the port where you want the `httpstream` to be sent to

Comment: When I run the command, it says: output debug: using sout  chain=`transcodesamplerate=44100:httpdst=0.0.0.0:9000'
main stream output debug: stream=`9000'
main stream out debug: looking for sout stream module: 0 candidates
main stream out debug: no sout stream module matched "9000"
main stream out debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.155 ms - Total 0.155 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.155 ms)
main stream out debug: destroying chain... (name=(null))
main stream out debug: destroying chain done
main stream output error: stream chain failed for `transcodesamplerate=44100:httpdst=0.0.0.0:9000'

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert quotes in right way:

```
cvlc rtsp://192.168.13.162:554/ :sout='#transcode{vcodec=FLV1,vb=2048,fps=25,scale=1,acodec=none,deinterlace}:http{mime=video/x-flv,mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=0.0.0.0:5555/}' :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=5 :sout-keep :no-audio --rtsp-caching 10200 --video --no-sout-audio --udp-caching=30000 --http-caching=5000
```